# Embedding Workbench JBPM In Application

Tags: embed, jbpm, workbench

i'm newbie in jbpm, i want to display some jbpm perspective in my web application, i do like this example

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="ifrm" height='800' src='http://localhost:8080/jbpm-console?standalone=true&perspective=Tasks List&header=ComplementNavArea' width='1000'></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Inside src attribute of iframe i have perspective and header parameter. In example, they have values but i don't know where they get those values.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Those are the id defined by the perspective.

org.kie.workbench.common.screens.home.client.perspectives.HomePerspective
org.kie.workbench.client.perspectives.AdministrationPerspective
org.kie.workbench.client.perspectives.DroolsAuthoringPerspective
org.guvnor.m2repo.client.perspectives.GuvnorM2RepoPerspective
Process Instances With Details
Process Instances
Process Definitions With Details
Process Definitions
Tasks With Details
Tasks
Identity
Jobs
DashboardPerspective
Deployments

And here are the available headers... (you can add more than one if you like):
LogoWidget
AppNavBar
ComplementNavArea

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Kris Verlaenen! I will try this.