# How to use JBPM Process Modeller in an external GWT code?

Tags: gwt, jbpm

I'm trying to integrate JBPM with my GWT project and I want to create Process Definitions and Instances, using REST Remote APIs.

For the creation of Project definitions, can I integrate the process modeller from the KIE workbench into my GWT code (something similar to iFrame)? Does JBPM expose any APIs to do that?  or is there any GWT component which could render this external component?

I don't want to use iFrame, because according to one of the JBOSS documents I was reading, "The designer opened in stand-alone mode using the link: http://localhost:8080/designer/editor?profile=jbpm&uuid=123456 allows you to only view existing processes, and not save any edits nor create new ones."

This would hold good even if I use the designer using iFrame? How do I make sure that the edits are saved?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for remote process modelling. However, you can embed various bits of the kie-workbench in your web application using iFrame.

More info can be found here

http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch09.html#wb.Embedding

[Embedding Workbench JBPM In Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960628/embedding-workbench-jbpm-in-application)

Comment: I don't want to use iFrame because I read this in one of the documents:

"The designer may also be opened stand-alone by using the following link: http://localhost:8080/designer/editor?profile=jbpm&uuid=123456 (where 123456 should be replaced by the uuid of a process stored in Guvnor). Note that running designer in this way allows you to only view existing processes, and not save any edits nor create new ones."

Is there any other way?

Comment: You can embed whole kie-workbench using iFrame which allows you to create new assets. If you would decide to create new process, then Web Designer would be started for modelling that process.